# Batch Rename Images - but keep original file, always

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Usually, I open cmd and use

```
ren oldname.jpg newname.jpg
```

and that works fine, but now I have an issue where I have to rename the same file into 50 or 100 different names.

How can I rename these, but keep the original file (so that I can continue saving it as a different name).

Thanks!

Comment: That would be making a copy (or copies) instead of renaming, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need several copies from the same file. This should do it.

```
copy oldname.jpg newname.jpg
```

Comment: That easy, eh? You are my hero.

Comment: This is for one single new file. Do you also need help in making script to automate those 100 files?

Comment: It's actually 400,000 - but I just copy/paste into CMD after setting them up in excel.

Comment: Looks like copy/paste won't work in CMD with copy for some reason (where as ren will). Do you know how I would make a batch file for this with a rename?

Comment: No worries. I just did: copy /y "c:\location\file.txt" "c:\newlocation\newfile.txt" in a bat file - all went well.